# How to make UINavigationController touches pass through

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, touch-event

What I want to achieve basically is to have two navigation controllers presented at the same time (their views should be one over the other). I want the navigation controller's view that is on top to forward the touches to the navigation controller below if the touch is not on some element presented in the top navigation controller (subview of top navigation controller's view).
I tried multiple approaches but none seem to work. The closest to the solution I got was using the below method in the `view` property of the view controller. This is working for regular view controllers but I think navigation controller has some subviews that interfere with it.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!self.forwardTouchesToSubviews) {
        return NO;
    }
    BOOL pointInSubview = NO;

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        if (!view.isHidden && CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point)) {
            CGPoint newPoint = [view convertPoint:point fromView:self];
            pointInSubview = [view pointInside:newPoint withEvent:event];

            if (pointInSubview) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

For my app having the navigation structured this way would simplify the navigation logic a lot and it seems to me that is very flexible solution in many cases, but I can't seem to make it work.

**Edit**

To make things simple. Lets say I have a background navigation controller (has some nice animations that form a background for the app). Over that there are all kinds of UI elements (controls, buttons, things that give functionality to the app) that do not cover the whole screen so the background is still visible. These elements compose multiple screens (so a navigation controller would be necessary). Also there could be multiple backgrounds that change independent of the UI elements above hence the need for a navigation controller (some other controller could be used here but lets say we use a navigation controller for the sake of the example). To complicate things even more touching the areas that do not contain UI elements should provide some animation feedback (so the background controller) should intercept the touches that are not captured by the above UI elements.

I hope that this clarifies what I am trying to do.

Comment: Can we see a diagram or something to further clarify how you expect this to work?  I'm not really sure how two stacked navigation controllers will make this easier for you, seems like it would only complicate things.

Comment: I added some more context to the question. Hopefully now its more clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The only solution I found is to override `hitTest(_:with:)` in a view containing both navigation controllers and check if a returning view is an instance of `UIViewControllerWrapperView`. Ugly, but works.